# Inserv warning missing LSB tags and overrides

Tags: linux, jetty

I installed Jetty 8 to my Debian server. When I added jetty to update-rc.d, it gives following warning. What is this and should I care about it?

```
insserv: warning: script 'jetty.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning means that your script misses special text comment which specifies services which your service depends on, runlevels on which it should be started or stopped (including ordering), etc.

See http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot for particular details on Debian.